# Как отсортировать 3 элемента?

Tags: java, сортировка, условия

Недавно начал учить Java и в качестве практической задачи нужно написать приложение, которое должна сравнивать 3 возраста и выдавать результат, кто самый старший, младший и между ними.

Так же была дана "методичка" в которой изложена суть логики всего этого. Но или я дурак, или лыжи не едут, но именно такое решение задачи мне просто не дается.
Я просто путаюсь что с чем уже сравнивал и не могу двинуться дальше.

Я не прошу решения этой задачи, просто подскажите - какие еще варианты решения этой задачи можно использовать ? Метод решения, на котором настаивает учитель мне не подходит.

```
public class Loader
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer damirAge = 30;
    Integer tolanAge = 25;
    Integer uraAge = 55;
    Integer oldest;
    Integer youngest;
    Integer middle;

    if (damirAge >= tolanAge && damirAge >= uraAge)
        oldest = damirAge;
    else if (tolanAge >= damirAge && tolanAge >= uraAge)
        oldest = tolanAge;
    else
        oldest = uraAge;

    if (damirAge <= tolanAge && damirAge <= uraAge)
        youngest = damirAge;
    else if (tolanAge <= damirAge && tolanAge <= uraAge)
        youngest = tolanAge;
    else
        youngest = uraAge;

    if (damirAge >= tolanAge && damirAge <= uraAge)
        middle = damirAge;

    else if (tolanAge >= uraAge && tolanAge <= damirAge)
        middle = tolanAge;
    else
        middle = uraAge;

    System.out.println("Most young " + youngest);
    System.out.println("Middle " + middle);
    System.out.println("Most old " + oldest);
}
}
```

Comment: Нарисуйте на бумажке в виде блок-схемы. Вы же проходили блок-схемы? (что-то по типу https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-019800883fad1adf7285a87692fa7146-c)

Comment: Нет, такого не было. Сейчас попробую, но основная проблема для меня состоит в том, что я банально путаюсь что с чем уже сравнивал.
Сейчас нарисую предложенную вами схему, возможно мне это поможет, спасибо.
Просто меня реально угнетает факт. что это самое начало и я уже имею такие трудности.

Comment: Нужно обязательно использовать if else, или можно использовать различные механизмы?

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать массив, например, и отсортировать его? Такие задачи решаются именно так обычно.

Comment: Использовать нужно именно else if, но т.к. у меня с этим проблемы, хотел бы узнать и другие способы решения. И отправить именно его, с пометкой что я вижу решение этой задачи именно так, т.к. считаю его более лаконичным, чем тот, который требуется сделать.
Поможет врятли и работу скорее всего не примут, но я просто в отчаянии. Самое начало моего обучения и уже сталкиваюсь с такими проблемами. Чувствую, будто я не могу вникнуть даже в базис

Comment: Если с самого начала такие проблемы, то для начала упростите себе задачу. Я бы вместо заморских имен переменных обозвал их, например, a, b, c. Уже меньше бокоф, меньше путаницы будет. Замените двойное сравнение (<=, >=)  на просто >, < - если значения a,b,c разные, результат будет таким же, а символов меньше, читабельность повысится. Там и разберетесь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что задание предполагало всё-таки освоение логики вложенных операторов if.

По анализу математической подоплёки:
Возможных результатов (перестановок) может быть 6 (если не учитывать случаи равенства). На получение 6 исходов нужно по меньшей мере 2.58 бита информации, т.е. эта задача требует в идеале выполнения **не более** трёх сравнений. Это в данном случае реализуемо - сравнений будет 2 или 3 (в среднем 2.667):

```
if A > B:
       if A > C:
              if B > C:
                    A B C
              else:
                    A C B  
        else:    
           C A B
else:
      if B > C:
             if C > A:
                    B C A
             else:
                    B A C
      else:
          C B A
```

Comment: Да это и требовалось, но изложено было далеко не так наглядно как это сделали вы.

Answer (score 7):

Такое странное решение, подходящее для случая именно трёх возрастов:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer damirAge = 30;
    Integer tolanAge = 25;
    Integer uraAge = 55;
    Integer oldest = Math.max(Math.max(damirAge, tolanAge), uraAge);
    Integer youngest = Math.min(Math.min(damirAge, tolanAge), uraAge);
    Integer middle = (damirAge + tolanAge + uraAge) - oldest - youngest;

    System.out.println("Most young " + youngest );
    System.out.println("Middle " + middle);
    System.out.println("Most old " + oldest);
}
```

Поскольку внутри `Math.max/min` по сути своей является условным выражением, это решение можно передалать под вашу задачу с `if/else`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer damirAge = 30;
    Integer tolanAge = 25;
    Integer uraAge = 55;
    Integer oldest;
    Integer youngest;
    Integer middle;

    if(damirAge > tolanAge){
        oldest = damirAge;
    } else {
        oldest = tolanAge;
    }
    if(uraAge > oldest){
        oldest = uraAge;
    }

    if(damirAge < tolanAge){
        youngest = damirAge;
    } else {
        youngest = tolanAge;
    }
    if(uraAge < youngest){
        youngest = uraAge;
    }

    middle = (damirAge + tolanAge + uraAge) - oldest - youngest;

    System.out.println("Most young " + youngest );
    System.out.println("Middle " + middle);
    System.out.println("Most old " + oldest);
}
```

Но делать нужно конечно через массивы, как ответил `@gil9red`, на мой взгляд в качестве учебного задания на `if/else` можно подобрать гораздо более уместные примеры, чем этот.

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант как по мне просто шикарен. Он позволяет получить нужный результат, при этом мне его легко читать и понимать.
В отличие от моего, первоначального варианта, в котором я сам же и путался.

Answer (score 5):

> просто подскажите - какие еще варианты решения этой задачи можно
> использовать

Условия нужны, но в этой задаче, мне кажется, проще будет другой подход:

- Получаем 3 возраста
- Помещаем их в коллекцию, например в список
- Сортируем список
- После сортировки, первым элементом будет самый младший, потом средний и последним старший

Код:

```
Integer damirAge = 30;
Integer tolanAge = 25;
Integer uraAge = 55;

List<Integer> ages = Arrays.asList(damirAge, tolanAge, uraAge);
System.out.println(ages);  // [30, 25, 55]

// Сортируем
Collections.sort(ages);
System.out.println(ages);  // [25, 30, 55]

Integer youngest = ages.get(0);
Integer middle = ages.get(1);
Integer oldest = ages.get(2);

System.out.println("Most young " + youngest);
System.out.println("Middle " + middle);
System.out.println("Most old " + oldest);
```

Результат:

```
Most young 25
Middle 30
Most old 55
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Integer damirAge = 30;
Integer tolanAge = 25;
Integer uraAge = 55;
Integer oldest;
Integer youngest;
Integer middle;

if (damirAge >= tolanAge && damirAge >= uraAge){
    oldest = damirAge;
    if (tolanAge >= uraAge){
       middle = tolanAge;
       youngest = uraAge;
    }else{
       middle = uraAge;
       youngest = tolanAge;
    }
}
else if (tolanAge >= damirAge && tolanAge >= uraAge){
    oldest = tolanAge;
    if (damirAge >= uraAge){
       middle = damirAge;
       youngest = uraAge;
    }else{
       middle = uraAge;
       youngest = damirAge;
    }
}else{
    oldest = uraAge;
    if (damirAge >= tolanAge){
       middle = damirAge;
       youngest = tolanAge;
    }else{
       middle = tolanAge;
       youngest = damirAge;
    }
}
```

Справедливости стоит добавить что данный алгоритм отработает быстрее чем вариант с сортировкой списка, просто потому что не будем выделять место для списка.

В лучшем случае проведем 3 сравнения `Integer`, в худшем- 5, мат. ожидание примерно равно 4.