# Код сортировки чисел не работает при одинаковых числах (c++)

Tags: c++

Почти дописал код и столкнулся с проблемой в одном из модулей кода. Если числа разные легко сортирует, но если одинаковые ничего не выводит. Что не так? ( Я вводил 1 1 2, или 2 2 3 к примеру)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    if ((a > b) && (b > c)) std::cout << c << b << a;
    else if ((a > c) && (c > b))   std::cout << b << " " << c << " " << a;
    else if ((b > c) && (c > a))   std::cout << a << " " << c << " " << b;
    else if ((b > a) && (a > c))   std::cout << c << " " << a << " " << b;
    else if ((c > a) && (a > b))   std::cout << b << " " << a << " " << c;
    else if ((c > b) && (b > a))   std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
    else if ((a == b) && (b == c)) std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
    else if ((a == b) && (b > c))  std::cout << c << " " << b << " " << a;
    else if ((a == c) && (c > b))  std::cout << b << " " << a << " " << c;
    else if ((b == c) && (b > a))  std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
    return 0;

}
```

(PS: я наверное перепутал битовые и логические операторы, но это не точно)

Comment: Почему же не выводит? Выводит: https://ideone.com/Q2FHSk

Comment: Я прикрепил скрин

Comment: У вас может выполняться до **20** сравнений, тогда как достаточно трёх. Может быть, вам [что-то такое нужно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/867025/291659)?

Comment: А у вас нет такой ветки вообще, которая бы соответствовала введенным числам...

Comment: кажется буфер потока вывода надо почистить в конце программы `std::cout<<std::flush;`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Нет, это тут ни при чем...

Comment: отладка Visual страдает от этого постоянно в винде. @Harry

Comment: @AlexGlebe В данном случае у него нет ни одной ветки, которая бы соответствовала введенным значениям.

Comment: тогда нужно всего-лишь `3!=3*2*1==6` условий, только использовать сравнение `>=` : `((a >= c) && (c >= b))` .. и т.д.

Comment: а в существующем коде можно что то исправить для правильной работы? А то не понимаю что не так уже сделал

Comment: (Я нашел ошибку, я забыл написать, что если значение будет больше чем дано)

Comment: [Как быстро отсортировать 3 элемента?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/789961)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if ((a == b) && (b < c))  std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;

//добавьте эту условия и работает так, как вы хотели.
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать для этого не кучу условий, а какую-нибудь встроенную функцию, благо в плюсах такая есть. Код ниже при должном желании можно переделать даже для сортировки N чисел. Сейчас он написан для работы с тремя числами как ты и просил, причём числа могут быть и повторяющимися - программа не сломается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
cout << "Введите сразу 3 числа" << endl;
int a, b, c;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
vector<int> sorted = vector<int>();
sorted.push_back(a);
sorted.push_back(b);
sorted.push_back(c);

sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());

cout << "Отсортированный вектор из трёх чисел" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < sorted.size(); i++)
    cout << sorted[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Для переносимости у `main` должен быть возвращаемый тип `int`.

Comment: @tocic почему? что ты имеешь ввиду под переносимостью?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function, https://godbolt.org/z/zYWqoYGTf